# WPF not showing one collection

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

i have two observable Collections that my view is binded to, one is called Network.Nodes and one it Network.Connections - the Network object is a Property in my view model.

I'm getting data from BackgroundWorker and adding new Node\Connection via the BW.ProgressChanged.

When the BW finish it's work i see only nodes and no connection. i added a Debug.WriteLine("Network.Connection.Cout = " + Network.Connection.Cout); 
On the BW finish work, and i see that there are 2 elements inside (which is the correct amount) but for some reason i don't see the elements.

The ProgressChanged:

```
if (e.ProgressPercentage == 2)      //Add connection to UI
        {
            ConnectionViewModel tempCon = new ConnectionViewModel();
            List<Object> ConnectionObj = new List<object>();
            ConnectionObj = (List<Object>)e.UserState;
            tempCon.SourceConnector = (ConnectorViewModel)ConnectionObj[0];
            tempCon.DestConnector = (ConnectorViewModel)ConnectionObj[1];
            Network.Connections.Add(tempCon);
```

This is how i call the ProgressChange:

```
                        List<Object> connectionObj = new List<Object>();

                        connectionObj.Add(connection.SourceConnector);
                        connectionObj.Add(connection.DestConnector);
                        connectionObj.Add(connection.Type);
                        connectionObj.Add(i++);

                        bw.ReportProgress(2, connectionObj);
```

The binding:

```
     NodesSource="{Binding Network.Nodes}"
     ConnectionsSource="{Binding Network.Connections}"
```

The Network in the View Model:

```
  public NetworkViewModel Network
    {
        get
        {
                return network;
        }
        set
        {
                network = value;

                OnPropertyChanged("Network"); 
        }
    }
```

The Network View Model has two observableCollections one is of type NodeView model and one is ConnectionViewModel.

the Connection View model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Utils;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows;

namespace YogevAfekaRAPAT.YNIDS.ViewModels
{
/// <summary>
/// Defines a connection between two connectors (aka connection points) of two nodes.
/// </summary>
public sealed class ConnectionViewModel : AbstractModelBase
{
    #region Internal Data Members

    /// <summary>
    /// The source connector the connection is attached to.
    /// </summary>
    private ConnectorViewModel sourceConnector = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// The destination connector the connection is attached to.
    /// </summary>
    private ConnectorViewModel destConnector = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// The source and dest hotspots used for generating connection points.
    /// </summary>
    private Point sourceConnectorHotspot;
    private Point destConnectorHotspot;

    /// <summary>
    /// Points that make up the connection.
    /// </summary>
    private PointCollection points = null;

    #endregion Internal Data Members

    public enum ConnectorType
    {
        REGULAR = 0,
        FLOW = 1
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The source connector the connection is attached to.
    /// </summary>
    public ConnectorViewModel SourceConnector
    {
        get
        {
            return sourceConnector;
        }
        set
        {
            if (sourceConnector == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (sourceConnector != null)
            {
                sourceConnector.AttachedConnections.Remove(this);
                sourceConnector.HotspotUpdated -= new EventHandler<EventArgs>(sourceConnector_HotspotUpdated);
            }

            sourceConnector = value;

            if (sourceConnector != null)
            {
                sourceConnector.AttachedConnections.Add(this);
                sourceConnector.HotspotUpdated += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(sourceConnector_HotspotUpdated);
                this.SourceConnectorHotspot = sourceConnector.Hotspot;
            }

            OnPropertyChanged("SourceConnector");
            OnConnectionChanged();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The destination connector the connection is attached to.
    /// </summary>
    public ConnectorViewModel DestConnector
    {
        get
        {
            return destConnector;
        }
        set
        {
            if (destConnector == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (destConnector != null)
            {
                destConnector.AttachedConnections.Remove(this);
                destConnector.HotspotUpdated -= new EventHandler<EventArgs>(destConnector_HotspotUpdated);
            }

            destConnector = value;

            if (destConnector != null)
            {
                destConnector.AttachedConnections.Add(this);
                destConnector.HotspotUpdated += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(destConnector_HotspotUpdated);
                this.DestConnectorHotspot = destConnector.Hotspot;
            }

            OnPropertyChanged("DestConnector");
            OnConnectionChanged();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The source and dest hotspots used for generating connection points.
    /// </summary>
    public Point SourceConnectorHotspot
    {
        get
        {
            return sourceConnectorHotspot;
        }
        set
        {
            sourceConnectorHotspot = value;

            ComputeConnectionPoints();

            OnPropertyChanged("SourceConnectorHotspot");
        }
    }

    public Point DestConnectorHotspot
    {
        get
        {
            return destConnectorHotspot;
        }
        set
        {
            destConnectorHotspot = value;

            ComputeConnectionPoints();

            OnPropertyChanged("DestConnectorHotspot");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Points that make up the connection.
    /// </summary>

    public PointCollection Points
    {
        get
        {
            return points;
        }
        set
        {
            points = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("Points");
        }
    }


    private ConnectorType type;
    public ConnectorType Type
    {
        get
        {
            return type;
        }
        set
        {
            type = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("Type");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event fired when the connection has changed.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ConnectionChanged;

    #region Private Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the 'ConnectionChanged' event.
    /// </summary>
    private void OnConnectionChanged()
    {
        if (ConnectionChanged != null)
        {
            ConnectionChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }


    #endregion Private Methods

}
```

}

Comment: Normally what I would try is to bind the view to a list already loaded in my ViewModel (no background worker), just to discard naming issues (i.e: wrong property names, this happens often with XAML), did you try that already?

Comment: Make sure you have FirstChance Exceptions on to see possible Exceptions like updating the UI from a background thread)

Comment: I need to get data from database

Comment: @Gope what do you mean?

Comment: If you created the BackgroundWorker in another Thread (not UI) it will raise the progresschanged on that Thread, meaning a crossthread exception may occure. In VS you can turn on FirstChance Exceptions (if not already active). You may not see them otherwise... (http://florianreischl.blogspot.de/2010/01/how-to-enable-first-chance-exceptions.html)

Comment: I did create the BackgroungWorker on the UI thread, please view the comment on the answer of @Gope i just added an important thing

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but it might be that you're trying to update the collections from the background worker, which can result in problems. You need to marshal that to the UI-Thread using a Dispatcher like:

```
view.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                            Network.Connections.Add(tempCon);
                        }), DispatcherPriority.Normal);
```

A Dispatcher can be found on all UI-Elements. Not sure how your code is structured so can't tell where to get one from without seeing more code or getting more information.

Comment: I'm updating the `Network.Connection` only in the ProgressChanged, isn't that happens on the UI thread?

Comment: Not neccessarily: The event is raised on the thread that created the worker...

BTW: for a dispatcher you could of course use: Application.Current.Dispatcher...

Comment: The most annoying part is that the `Network.Nodes` are there. and when the backgroundWorker finish i'm writing to debug the count of the `Network.Connections` and see all the data of the two element. so the data is there, why does the view not showing it?

Comment: Ok, then that should not be your problem. :)

Comment: Please view the last comment i added

Comment: I am sorry but this appears to be some small problem specific to your code. I's suggest you use Snoop (http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ - use the zip/no installer) find your UI-Element in the Tree. Then search for ItemsSource in the Properties Tab. You will see a green or red indicator wether the binding works. Clicking right in that line and choosing "Delve" moves you into the collection. There you should see your entries or not. The rest depends on your findings.